# Optimizing web scraping with puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I am making a request for an API which allows to scrape a web page.

I use expressJS and Postman for testing and I use puppeter and cheerio for scraping.

It works but when testing with Postman, the execution time of the request is between 8s and 13s.

I find that it is taking too much time, I would like to know if this is normal, knowing that I have not yet deploy in production my API,
I'm only testing it locally for now.

I try with a good connection.

**EDIT**

I wrote the function, with an async / await promise, the execution time is on average between 2.5s and 4s.

It looks like it is still taking time.

Are there other ways to optimize this request?

Example of the script I use with the medium site :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const scrapURL = (req, res, next) => {

  let url = req.query.url;

  puppeteer.launch({ headless:true }).
    then(async function(browser) {
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        page.on('request', request => {
            if (request.resourceType() === 'document')  
                request.continue();
            else
            request.abort();
        });
    
        await page.goto(url);

        const data = await page.$eval("h1", element => element.innerText);

        await browser.close();

        return res.status(201).json({ data:data});
        
    })
   .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error:error }))
  }
```

Comment: Can you add to your code axample how your `$ = cheerio.load...` is set up? Without that we are unable to run your snippet. Question: are there any particular reason for using promises instead of async/await syntax?

Comment: I imported cheerio, then I was able to recover the title h1 of my url, the script works just I do not understand why the process is so slow.

I updated my post

Comment: Two more questions: (1) is it intentional that you are not closing the browser in the end of the scraping? Are you calling the scraping script multiple times so you want to reuse the opened browser instance? (2) I am asking why you favor the old js promise over async/await syntax because it would make your scraper script much more handy when it comes to puppeteer scripting, but if you are using older version than Node 8 of course you have no other choice than the older promise format. So: async/await is not an option?

Comment: BTW, you do not need cheerio with puppeteer. `const data = $("h1", html).text();` can be replaced with `const data = await page.$eval("h1", element => element.innerText);`. This eliminates one dependency and HTML reparsing with  cheerio (HTML is already parsed by puppeteer into DOM).

Comment: I updated my post.

I think I forgot to close the browser, I need to open the browser only once.

The script will execute, each time I call a post request from my Rest API, so I only need one instance.

Async / await would be more practical indeed ...

I have the latest version of node to install

Comment: I updated the code with your recommendation.

Comment: If these 2.5-4s include opening and closing the browser, this seems like an unavoidable delay. Maybe you can preserve the opened browser and connect to it each time?

Comment: Yes it is inevitable, I wanted if the time if it concerned the majority of people or if my text was optimal. I don't know if keeping the browser open is a good thing, especially if I plan to use the app for a long time.

Comment: You can measure the time between `puppeteer.launch()` is resolved and `browser.close()` is called to be sure if this is a code issue or just a browser launching overheads.

Answer (score 0):

I just performed tests with the perf_hooks library
on the puppeteer script.

The execution time of the request is between 0.80 ms and 1.24 ms.

So it's time to open the browser that takes time.

I had thought of launching the browser when I started my server, but if I do several scraping, I would have to open a new page each time.

Won't it make the process cumbersome and lengthen the execution time ?